# Convert Array of "true,false or 0,1" to byte array then write it as a file

Tags: c#, binary, bit, binarywriter

I'm asking a simple question but i can't find the easiest way to do that, my application read a small file, *Simply the 8 bytes word* "**uploaded**" read from just 8 byte file, will be a binary array of **0,1...** or list of **true-false** and the length is **8*8= 64 bits**, NOW I already have this 64 bits in a array of string and also list of Boolean, the code below is faster and i just need to edit the code to give me a 8-bits per time not 1 byte..**** with **MemoryStream**

```
 string path = openFileDialog1.FileName;
 byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
 MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(file);
 BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(memory);

 for (int i = 0; i <= file.Length - 1; i++)
 {

 byte result = reader.ReadByte();

 }
```

After editing this code, i just need to write back this bits

> 01110101-01110000-01101100-01101111-01100001-01100100-01100101-01100100 **to be uploaded**

to bytes then Write it back to a valid file.?? i'm really tired because i see many methods to write a bytes array as a file but not a bits... i'm tired because i can't find a way out !!

Comment: possibly [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you need

Comment: A byte *is* 8 bits. If you want each bit of a byte, one at a time, you can use `BitArray`, or can use bitwise operators, but your question as its written is unclear. There also doesn't appear to be any point in your usage of `MemoryStream` and `BinaryReader` from what you've posted.

Comment: how i can do something like BinaryWriter.Write() but in bitArray

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [BitArray constructor accepting a byte array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk7f5c5(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var bitArray = new BitArray(new byte[] { result });
```

Then you can call [`bitArray.Get(n)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.get(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the bit at position `n` of the `result` byte.

As for your edit, the code can be reduced to this:

```
string output = "";
byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
var bitArray = new BitArray(fileBytes);

// Loop over all bits in the bitarray, containing all bytes read from the file.
for (int i = 0; i < bitArray.Length; i++)
{
    output += bitArray.Get(i) ? "1" : "0";

    // Output a dash every 8 characters.
    if ((i + 1) % 8 == 0)
    {
        output += "-"
    }
}

// Write `output` string to file.
```

Comment: Really Thank you so much for your help, so what i'm thinking is true?? i already have the code above to read byte each time.. then i just need to compare the bits then read another 1 byte, how i can  reverse BACK the bits array to be bytes array then write the bits i have read to be a valid file??

Comment: I don't know, some example input and output (in your question, not a comment) would really help.

Comment: Thank you for your help again, but i need a array of 64 bit, so after finish reading all the bytes. i'll get a bitArray of 64?? or just the last byte?

Comment: thank you again, but i swear this is not a homework, i'm working on something greater, something in my work. but you believe me if i told you i have a 1 year working on this project, i do everything harder than this.. but i have a two problem's i can't fix.. can i just tell you that's problem's not to fix it. just i can comfort after this hard hard hard work, please listen to my issue??

Comment: I understand, but sometimes hard work is all it takes. Now try my code and try to explain what doesn't work about it.

Comment: visual studio debug stopped working when i load a image file.. around 1Mb or 2Mb...,, that's why i need to use MemoryStream.. becuase when i use the code above in my question.. when i load 200Mb .. there's no problem.. maybe there's no answer to my question " how i can edit the MemoryStream Code above .. so it can give me a boolean or binary not byte!, any suggestion?

Comment: Yeah I think you should use a BinaryReader to read chunks of bytes from the file as opposed to File.ReadAllBytes at once.